# Word or a phrase that describe both type of departmental store with typical business model

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to differentiate between two department stores.

Let's say a department store which for each product like a jeans or printed shirt with a particular design and color has all the available sizes.

While the other department store bring almost only one piece of such a jeans or printed shirt. And this almost always happens for their other products, may it be belt, cap, shoes, etc.

This is to particularly highlight the business model they are following. In case of the first department store there is a high probability that you will see lot of people in the town wearing same jeans.

While with the second department store since you find only one piece you will find rarity making the customer exclusive and feel special.

So i want a placeholder word or words that describe both department store that promote their own business model

Hypothetical Example: While DEBMN, France is typical _____ type department stores (has sizes for product), Sers,Turkey on the other hand is a type of  _____  department stores (have one or two piece for each product).

Comment: For now I am concentrating only on clothing so as to bring out the business model that they result in. If I discuss other products the question will be diluted. @KannE

Comment: @KannE  It's _departmental store/ department store_ as per _Dictionary.com._

Comment: If you mean that one sells a small number of mass-produced lines at high volume, and the other specializes in pieces with small production runs produced by small-scale artisan producers, I think you'd have to specify the difference with a descriptive phrase like those I just used. But it's also possible that a store has small amounts of products for other reasons, e.g. because they sell surplus/overstock sourced from a mass-market supplier. You could distinguish mass-market, mass-produced goods from niche/artisan/small-run/hand-made, but in my experience many department stores will sell both.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you don't mean department store — no department store would carry one or two pieces of each product.

If you're talking about two clothing stores with different business models, the second store, in Turkey, would probably be called a "boutique." You might call it a "gallery," if the clothing is artistic and exclusive. A store like that carries products that you might call "limited edition," "limited run," or "one-of-a-kind."

I think I'd call the first store, in France, a "retail store" — that seems like the opposite of a boutique in this context. It could also be a "clothing store" or "department store" (but department stores sell a lot more things than just clothing).